# Como pegar uma string retornada da execução interna de uma URL para transformá-la em um objeto JSON?

Tags: php, javascript, json, web-service

Preciso executar [esta URL](https://sandbox.boletobancario.com/boletofacil/integration/api/v1/fetch-payment-details?paymentToken=1234) internamente no servidor.
O resultado da execução gera uma string no formato JSON:

```
{"success":false,"errorMessage":"Token inválido"}
```

Como pegar a string retornada da execução da URL para transformá-la em um objeto JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essa string já vem no formato JSON, para transformar num objeto usa o metodo [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-decode.php);

Usando PHP tem pelos menos duas maneiras:

**Usando [curl](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.curl.php):**

```
$url = 'https://sandbox.boletobancario.com/boletofacil/integration/api/v1/fetch-payment-details?paymentToken=1234';
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, True);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1');
$rawData = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$data = json_decode($rawData);
print_r($data); // stdClass Object ( [success] => [errorMessage] => Token inválido )
```

**Usando [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-get-contents.php):**

```
$url = 'https://sandbox.boletobancario.com/boletofacil/integration/api/v1/fetch-payment-details?paymentToken=1234';
$opts = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method'=>"GET",
        'ignore_errors' => true, // para este caso, isto é necessário senão seria ".. 400 Bad Request .."
        'header' => array(
            'User-Agent' => "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1",
        )
    ),
);
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$rawData = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
$data = json_decode($rawData);
print_r($data); // stdClass Object ( [success] => [errorMessage] => Token inválido )
```

Em para aceder às keys deste novo objeto (`$data`) faz:

```
$data->errorMessage; // Token inválido
```

Nota que nem sempre é preciso definir nos headers um `User-Agent`, mas para muitos casos o servidor a que vamos fazer o pedido "obriga" a que haja um  `User-Agent` definido, caso contrário a resposta vem vazia ou responde algum tipo de mensagem de erro

Comment: Muito bom Miguel. Eu tinha conseguido fazer aqui usando cURL. Ficou um pouco diferente mais funcionou também. Achei o segundo método interessante também. Valeu.

Answer (score 0):

Solução final galera! Utilizando cURL

```
$url = 'https://sandbox.boletobancario.com/boletofacil/integration/api/v1/fetch-payment-details?paymentToken='.$paymentToken;

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
// define que o conteúdo obtido deve ser retornado em vez de exibido
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$order = curl_exec($ch); //Pega a string JSON obtida.
curl_close($ch);
$array = json_decode($order, true); //transforma a string em um array associativo.
```